# Как сослаться на тип данных столбца из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  DEF_DEF_ID OtherTable.DEF_ID%TYPE
)
```

Ошибка:

> ORA-00911: неверный символ.

Ругается на процент перед `TYPE`.

Но разве не так нужно ссылаться на тип данных другого столбца из БД?

PS Что-то совсем простые вещи становятся камнем преткновения...

Comment: В `create table` нельзя ссылаться на типы колонок. все типы должны быть указаны явно

Comment: @Mike А как же отслеживать изменения в таблицах, поля которых могут стать внешним ключом для других таблиц?

Comment: А вы думаете `%TYPE` позволяет что то отслеживать, там где он используется ? Нет, не позволяет, он просто подставляет тип в момент компиляции объекта. Если тип колонки на которую идет ссылка изменится, потребуется перекомпиляция процедур. А в таблицах никакой "перекомпиляции" нет, единственный способ изменения типа колонки, давать явный `alter table`. А изменения вы сами должны отслеживать. Да и 95% всех ключей ссылаются на поля number. Вообще изменение типа колонки первичного ключа это что то сверхъестественное и потянет за собой гораздо больше проблем, чем изменение типа в связанных таблицах

Comment: Внешние ключи отслеживают изменение данных. А за типами и их согласованностью должен следить разработчик.

Comment: @Mike думаю, можно это вставить в ответ и закрыть, на ресурсе такого вопроса не заметил.

Answer (score 3):

> Но разве не так нужно ссылаться на тип данных другого столбца из БД?

Ссылаться на тип данных возможно только в PL/SQL, [%TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/TYPE-attribute.html#GUID-EAB44F7E-B2AB-4AC6-B83D-B586193D75FC) является частью его синтаксиса.

В SQL тип данных колонок всегда задаётся явно, аналога `%TYPE` нет.

В PL/SQL программах `%TYPE` служит для указания типа для переменных или параметров,  то есть элементов не содержащих персистентных данных. Изменится тип данных, на который ссылается `%TYPE`, PL/SQL программа становится недействительной и должна быть перекомпилированна:

```
create table t (col int);
/
create or replace procedure proc is
    val t.col%type := 9999;
begin null;
end;
/
exec proc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

alter table t modify col date;

exec proc

PLS-00905: object ME.PROC is invalid
```

В SQL столбцы содержат персистентные данные и изменять их тип, который был задан при создании таблицы, а также ссылаться на этот тип в других таблицах, имеет мало смысла.

```
alter table t modify col int;

Table T altered.

insert into t values (1);

1 row inserted.

alter table t modify col varchar2(32)
/
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
```